# Reversed Array Function in C

Tags: c

Hi I am trying to print a reversed array through a void function but my IDE is yelling with one errors : `expected expression before ']' token.`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>  
void printReverses(char szName[], char szReversedName[]);

int main(void)
{

    char szName[21] = "Perry Scope";
    char szReversedName[21];
    char arrRev = printReverses(szName[], szReversedName[]);
    printf("Name in reverse %s \n", arrRev);
    return 0;
}

void printReverses(char szName[], char szReversedName[])
{
    int i, j, lenName;


    lenName=strlen(szName);
    for(i=0, j=lenName-1; i<lenName; i++, j--)
    {
        szReversedName[i] = szName[j];
    }
    szReversedName[i]=szName[lenName];  //add null termination
    return;
}
```

Comment: Change `char arrRev = printReverses(szName[], szReversedName[]);` to `printReverses(szName, szReversedName);` and `printf("Name in reverse %s \n", arrRev);` to `printf("Name in reverse %s \n", szReversedName);`

Comment: Your printReverses function returns nothing, so arrRev will be null.

Comment: Then don't ignore the yells of the compiler and read it's error message, it will also tell you which line is causing the error.!

Comment: @eyllanesc It's a void function

Comment: @MatthewKerian but he wants that void function assign his return to a char which is not correct.

Comment: Use: `int main(void)
{
/* Variable declarations */
char szName[21] = "Perry Scope";
char szReversedName[21];
printReverses(szName, szReversedName);
printf("Name in reverse %s \n", szReversedName);
return 0;
}`

Comment: Sweet it Works Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**This is one way of doing it.Try this**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>  
void printReverses(char szName[], char szReversedName[]);

int main(void)
{

  char szName[21] = "Perry Scope";
  char szReversedName[21];
  printReverses(szName, &szReversedName);
  printf("Name in reverse %s \n",szReversedName);
  return 0;
}

void printReverses(char szName[], char *szReversedName)
{
  int i, j, lenName;


lenName=strlen(szName);
for(i=0, j=lenName-1; i<lenName; i++, j--)
{
    szReversedName[i] = szName[j];
}
szReversedName[i]=szName[lenName];  //add null termination

}
```